# Could not open new database 'DB Name'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted (SQL Server, Error: 948)

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

*Hi,

**The Case:**

I am trying to move a database from one server to another, source server has SQL Server 2008 R2, destination server has SQL Server 2008.

I copied the .mdf file only I tried to use query `sp_attach_db` and wizard attach but the was an error, as follows:

> Attach database failed for Server
>   'SERVER_NAME'. 
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)
>
> ----------------------- ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>   An exception occurred while executing
>   a Transact-SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ---
>
> The database 'DB_Name' cannot be
>   opened because it is version 661. This
>   server supports version 655 and
>   earlier. A downgrade path is not
>   supported. Could not open new database
>   'DB_Name'. CREATE DATABASE is aborted.
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 948)

Comment: You need to upgrade the destination server to R2. There's no way around it.

Comment: You **cannot** move a database from SQL Server 2008 **R2** "down" to SQL Server 2008. There's no way, no trick, no workaround - it just **doesn't work** - you need to move from same version to same version (or up - but you cannot go down)

Comment: Ok how to upgrade the destination server to R2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I dont think its possible to attach a database from a higher version of SQL server to a lower version.

Eg 2008 to 2003 is not ok,

going from 2003 to 2008 is ok.

You could try doing an import export data but I have not worked out how to attach it so far.

Comment: Thanks WraithNath for your fast replay, but there is no way to get or export tables data out of 2008 R2 to 2008?

Comment: Hi Owidat, I hhave never found a way to restore a higher version database to a lower one but if you right click on a database in SQL server you can choose to import data. Then in the wizard specify the server and database to import from. You may be able to import all objects to a new database created on the lower version SQL server. Might take a while to run but I have used this before to copy tables and data from other databases.